# How do I automatically create a linear model with the lowest AIC step

Tags: r

I am trying to create a model with the lowest AIC step, I have the code for getting the aic, but now I want to make a loop to automatically create a model with the lowest aic:

```
fullModel = lm(data$num ~ data$age + data$sex + 
data$chol + data$hd + data$ca)
nullModel = lm(num ~ 1)
model_aic = step(nullModel, scope=list(lower=nullModel, upper=fullModel), direction='both')
n = dim(data)[1]
model_bic <- step(nullModel, scope=list(lower=nullModel, upper=fullModel), direction='both', k=log(n))
```

I am trying to have the code automatically create a linear model with the lowest step from the model_aic and the model_bic so I can input different data without having to look at each output for the best fit.

Tried making a loop found on SO but no success:

```
mod_headers <- names(data[1:ncol(data)-1])
f <- function(mod_headers) {
  models <- list()
  k <- 1
  for (i in 1:length(mod_headers)) {
    tab <- combn(mod_headers, i)
    for(j in 1:ncol(tab)) {
      mod_tab_new <- c(tab[, j], "Data")
      models[[k]] <- glm(data$num ~ ., data = data[mod_tab_new], 
                         family = binomial(link = "logit"))
      k <- k + 1
    }
  }
  models[[which.min(sapply(models, AIC))]]
}
 
f(mod_headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's not working for you, but I suspect it's the use of `data$` throughout your formula. Things generally work better if you give just the variable *names*, and use the `data` argument ...

This seems to work fine (in this case the AIC- and BIC-selected models are the same ...)

```r
fullModel = lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
m_aic <- step(fullModel)
m_bic <- step(fullModel, k = log(nrow(mtcars)))
```